# Jest: Unit test toHaveBeenCalled() not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a small component in React which generates two random numbers on render, then asks the user to submit the sum of these numbers and if they are correct, increment their score.

The following code handles this game and works as intended in the browser:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export const randomNumber = () => {
  var maxNumber = 10;
  var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * maxNumber) + 1);
  return randomNumber;
}

class Arithmetic extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: '',
      numbers: {
        x: randomNumber(),
        y: randomNumber()
      },
      score: ''
    }

    this.updateVals = this.updateVals.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  updateVals() {
    this.setState({
      numbers: {
        x: randomNumber(),
        y: randomNumber()
      },
      score: this.state.score + 1
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      score: 0
    });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    var isCorrect = this.state.numbers.x + this.state.numbers.y == this.state.value ? this.updateVals()  : alert("Try again");
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="arithmetic">
        <div className="arithmetic__game">
          <div className="row arithmetic__row--details">
            <div className="arithmetic__score">
            Score:&nbsp;&nbsp;{this.state.score}
            </div>
            <div className="arithmetic__timer">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row arithmetic__row--main">
            <div className="arithmetic__examples">
              1 + 1 = 2<br/>
              2 + 1 = 3<br />
            </div> 
            <div className="arithmetic__game-container">
            What is {this.state.numbers.x} + {this.state.numbers.y}?
              <div className="arithmetic__form-container">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <label>
                    Answer: &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input className="input-field" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                  </label>
                  <button className="btn-submit" type="submit" onClick={(e) => (this.handleSubmit) ? this.handleSubmit(e) : null}>Submit</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
};
```

However, when trying to check whether or not updateVals is called when the sum of both numbers is entered correctly, this fails. I have checked to see if handleSubmit is called on simulation of the "Submit" button being clicked, and it is called. I have also checked the values of the *value* and *numbers* props to see if the states have been correctly updated, which they have.

However, when updateVals is called, the score is incremented (and again, this is shown in the browser). But when I try to simulate this in Jest, the score remains at 0 as it is when it is initialised.

My test is as follows:

```
it("passes with correct input", () => {
      const updateVals = jest.fn();
      const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
      Arithmetic.prototype.updateVals = updateVals;
      Arithmetic.prototype.handleSubmit = handleSubmit;
      let wrapper = mount(<Arithmetic />);

      wrapper.find('.input-field').instance().value = wrapper.update().state().numbers.x + wrapper.update().state().numbers.y;
      expect(wrapper.find('.input-field').instance().value).toEqual((wrapper.update().state().numbers.x + wrapper.update().state().numbers.y).toString());
      wrapper.find('.input-field').simulate('change');
      wrapper.find('.btn-submit').simulate('click');
      console.log(wrapper.update().state().numbers.x, wrapper.update().state().numbers.y, wrapper.update().state().value);
      expect(updateVals).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Running tests in the terminal shows that, for instance, if the numbers.x is **1** and numbers.y is **9** then the value key in state is **'10'**. I'm not sure why when I test handleSubmit, it gets called and the test passes but updateVals does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working, I removed any events from the submit button and tested the form itself which already calls onSubmit and tested that the score itself updated in the state.

```
it("passes with correct input", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Arithmetic />);
  const preventDefault = jest.fn();
  const currentScore = wrapper.update().state().score;

  wrapper.find('.input-field').simulate('change', {target: {value: wrapper.update().state().numbers.x + wrapper.update().state().numbers.y}});
  wrapper.find('.main-form').simulate('submit', { preventDefault });
  expect(wrapper.update().state().score).toEqual(currentScore+1);
});
```